# cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-12592: TNS:bad packet

Tags: python, oracle, rhel, cx-oracle

I am writing a Flask API, and am seeing a lot of failures when load testing.

Looking at the uwsgi logs, I am seeing something which looks a little nasty, which is:

cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-12592: TNS:bad packet

The oracle connection is working, as I am not seeing a complete failure, but this does seem to be what is terminating the http rest call prematurely in most cases.

What is causing this?  I am using RHEL, with cx_Oracle 7.23, connecting to 12C database.  I am using the Oracle thin client.

```
Exception on /api/read/maa [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/ariel/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/ariel/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/ariel/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/ariel/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/ariel/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/ariel/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/ariel/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/connexion/decorators/decorator.py", line 48, in wrapper
    response = function(request)
  File "/ariel/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/connexion/decorators/uri_parsing.py", line 144, in wrapper
    response = function(request)
  File "/ariel/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/connexion/decorators/validation.py", line 384, in wrapper
    return function(request)
  File "/ariel/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/connexion/decorators/parameter.py", line 121, in wrapper
    return function(**kwargs)
  File "./registrations.py", line 58, in read_maa_non_passive
    for row in cursor_ariel.fetchall():
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-12592: TNS:bad packet
Getting data and status code
```

----UPDATE---------

All my problems went away when I stopped connection pooling in cx_Oracle.  I originally had a single connection to oracle shared across the Flask application.  This have me failures in stress testing.  So I tried to be clever and use SessionPooling and acquire connections and release them at each service call.  Finally I went back to "bad practice" and create a completely new connection to Oracle for every single function call (api endpoint), and I now get 100% success rate across stress testing in Locust, even for the larger response calls which are 30mb json payloads.

Comment: For future readers, see your followup question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64379225/cx-oracle-sessionpool-root-of-all-flask-problems/64380546#64380546

Comment: threaded=True did indeed solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For people who don't/haven't read the comment threads, the solution was to start the pool with `threaded=True`.

See [How to use Python Flask with Oracle Database](https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/how-to-use-python-flask-with-oracle-database).

Answer (score -1):

can you please test it with regular client and come back with results ?

Instant client is a subset of regular client.

Comment: if I start adding other Oracle clients, experience tells me I am asking for trouble

Comment: To be honest, I have a solution now which will work for the scale of this internal BI app...and as far as I can make out, the unixODBC driver is a commercial driver from EasySoft

Comment: Also, the official Oracle tutorial on Flask and cx_Oracle tells you to use the instant client.  https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/how-to-use-python-flask-with-oracle-database

Comment: Don't try with 'regular' client - the libraries are just the same as in Instant Client.  Regarding not pooling, you won't get good perf without it.  Did you use threaded mode when starting the pool?  Can you Describe your load testing more so we get a better picture of what you are doing, the data types, and volume etc.  Use a new Oracle Instant Client e.g. 19c.

Comment: Since there are official Oracle ODBC Drivers available on Windows and Linux as well - see for linux
FAQ's About Oracle ODBC Drivers On Linux and Unix (Doc ID 1338404.1)
you can try regular client containing an Oracle ODBC Driver - or Instant Client with additional Oracle ODBC - both working with Python ODBC Interface (Tested this on windows and Linux). This works and you got a supported Product stack except pyodbc etc.Since Oracle ODBC Driver is build using Oracle Call Interface (OCI) and has been developed since Oracle8 22 years, you can perform traces on ODBC, OCI, Oracle Network level.